# Everything is same but diff says newline is different

Tags: newline, diff

[image]

like this, everything is same but I get error from diff because of different newline. What should I do?

Comment: You probably should configure your IDE to treat newline as either CR or CRLF. See for reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want `diff` to ignore differences in the line endings.
You could use the `--strip-trailing-cr` option:

```
diff --strip-trailing-cr file1 file2
```

With this option `diff` strips the trailing carriage return character before comparing the files.

Or use `-w`

```
diff -w file1 file2
```

To ignore differences in white spaces that include tab, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space.

Comment: this will be graded by professor who use makefile tool so I have to fix this problem in my code